# Pytorch model gradients no updating with some custom code

Tags: image, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, yolo

I have an object detection task that requires to recognise multiple objects from an image. The idea is to define a simple network from scratch (i.e. without using ready implementations of YoLo or similar algorithms). Our approach was to define an architecture that was able to detect a single bounding box, and then to execute different independent copies of the same model on the data in parallel. Our architecture was defined as the following:

```py
class MultiObjectNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, image_width, image_height, num_classes=13, num_boxes=5, device=torch.device('mps')):
        super(MultiObjectNet, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.initial_conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, device=self.device)
        self.initial_conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, device=self.device)
        self.initial_conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=2, stride=2, device=self.device)

        self.no_pools1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride=2, device=self.device)
        self.no_pools2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=1024, kernel_size=3, stride=3, device=self.device)
        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, device=self.device)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, device=self.device)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128, device=self.device)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=64, device=self.device)

        self.pc_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1, device=self.device)
        self.box_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=4, device=self.device)
        self.category_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=64, out_features=num_classes, device=self.device)

        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.num_boxes = num_boxes

    def __device__(self):
        return self.device    

    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.initial_conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.initial_conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.initial_conv3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)

        x = self.no_pools1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.no_pools2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        x = torch.transpose(x,1,3)[::,0][:,0]
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = F.relu(x)

        return self.sigmoid(self.pc_layer(x)), self.box_layer(x), self.category_layer(x)
```

The network outputs a triple $(P_C, [x_{min}, y_{min}, x_{max}, y_{max}], CAT)$, where the inner list contains the coordinates of the bounding box and $CAT$ is a probability distribution over the classes of the dataset.
The training and loss calculation were computed as following:

```py
nets = [ MultiObjectNet(resizing_width, resizing_height, device=torch.device('mps')) for _ in range(max_boxes) ]

loss_df = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(100)), columns=["loss"])

learning_rate = 1e-02
optims = [ torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9) for net in nets ]

bce_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()
mse_loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()
xent_loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


for epoch in range(5):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for batch_number, batch in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader)) :
        inputs, labels = batch
        batch_size = len(inputs)
        for i, (optim, net, label) in enumerate(zip(optims, nets, labels)) :
          pred_pc, pred_box, pred_category = net(inputs)
          y_pc, y_box, y_category = label[0].reshape(batch_size, 1), label[1].reshape(batch_size, 4), label[2].reshape(batch_size, num_classes)
          optim.zero_grad()
          confidence_loss = bce_loss(pred_pc, y_pc)
          box_loss = mse_loss(pred_box, y_box))
          category_loss = xent_loss(pred_category, y_category)
          loss = confidence_loss + box_loss + category_loss
          loss.backward()
          optim.step()
```

My model fails to generalize the problem and fixates on a single output, no matter the input given to the network (always outputs very similar confidence probabilities, boxes and categories distributions). By looking into the first layer parameters, I can see that the gradient is not None, thus I suppose that there is some kind of learning, but I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Hey! I see two things from a quick glance over your code:

1. Did you put your model in train mode (using net.train()), sometimes this can help as by default I believe they are in test mode. Though not sure you have layers that actually have different behavior in test and train.
2. Have you considered lowering your learning rate ? 1e-02 is quite high, try something lower like 1e-4 and see how the loss evolves.

It would help if you could provide a log of the training (in terms of loss, and maybe performance.) Thanks !

Comment: can you try with `optim.zero_grad()` before the forward pass through the model instead of after it ? Also put model in train mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "my model"? You have multiple independent models in your example, where each model is independently learning to recognize a single object in the input image. How do you aggregate the predictions from all those models during evaluation?